# Rendering HTML Form Received Data On The Browser

Tags: html

How to remove the (b' & \n) displayed by HTML form when accepting input, sending it to Python script & getting the output to be displayed:

```
<p id= "in">Please Do:<br />
<br />
1) Verify the serial.<br />
2) Input the serial.<br />
<form action="input" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
Serial Number:
<input type="text" name="param" required>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"><br />
<br />
{{data_input}}
{{data1|safe}}
<br />
<br />
</form>
</p>
```

The displayed output:

> b'xxx Added Successfully To Database...\n'

Comment: Have you looked python's native 'replace' method?  What version of python?  Boldfacing sections of your post isn't useful either

Comment: Welcome to SO. You may want to read [ask] and [mcve] and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) and find out why it often has the opposite effect.

Comment: Thanks all for your great help, this's my first post & am learning a lot from you. again thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your message is stored in a variable:

```
your_message = b'xxx Added Successfully To Database...\n'
formatted_message = your_message.replace(b'\n', b'')
```

Then output formatted_message. When using 
 tags in html, I would to such a replace on all messages shown to the user.

Edit: If you want to convert the bytes-object to a normal string, you can do following:

```
formatted_message = formatted_message.decode()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, really appreciated, based on my HTML code, how I can use your suggestion as am not familiar with HTMl at all, the Python output is coming through the code ({{data_input}}
{{data1|safe}})

Comment: This isn't HTML, it is some kind of template language, like Django, used within HTML. But if there is a template, it has to be filled somewhere by code. Dont't you have any code (.py files or whatever) related to your HTML-Template?

Comment: Again thanks for the great help, you're totally right, this HTML is built using Django & here's the view:----------------------- from django.shortcuts import render
import requests
import sys
from subprocess import run,PIPE
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse

def input(request):
        inp= request.POST.get('param')
        out= run([sys.executable,'/home//sdwan-lab/Desktop/wanosos/server/clamososrtr1.py',inp],shell=False,stdout=PIPE)
        return render(request,'claim/index.html',{'data1':out.stdout})
--------------------------------------------------

Comment: Thanks for your highlight, I pointed out the issue in the view & fixed it. You were very helpful